# .Net 4. View consumed web service headers and body from request and response

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, header

We're consuming a web service (web reference, not service reference), and I need a way to output the entire message being sent (including headers) and the message that gets received.

When I add the web reference, the generated base type of the client object to send the messages is `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`

I send the messages like so:

```
ApiService api = new ApiService();
// set the certificate and basic http network credentials

var response = api.SendRequest(messageObject);
```

I'm able to get the body of the request by serializing `messageObject`, but can't figure out how to get the full message with the headers.

Since I'm using a certificate and basic authentication, tools like Fiddler, etc. aren't getting me what I need, so I believe I have do something programmatically to pull whats sent and whats received prior to being encrypted with ssl.

**EDIT**

What I want to see if the data being sent and received to another service from within my WCF service.... e.g.:

```
// this function is within my WCF service
public ResponseModel Auth()
{
    // call to another service here... need to trace this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for tracing purposes I have had some success using the tracing capabilities of the System.Net libraries, you should be able to enable the tracing through configuration only.

It's described here: [How to: Configure Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx)

The resulting log file isn't the easiest to follow, but is described here: [Interpreting Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46fcs6sz.aspx)

Comment: I tried something similar. See the answer here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5b4f3450-1591-4dbe-89c0-4794fa07fb8d/   But when I use that, it only shows me the input and ouput to and from my WCF service. My WCF service called another service, and those are the messages I need to capture.

Comment: The link you sent is similar, but at a different level in the framework stack. Give the above a try, I got most mileage from the System.Net logging and because it's at that level you should get your onward client calls.